# Does the error (uncertainty) on chi2 exist?

Tags: statistics

Let's consider the chi2 quantity between two histograms :

- histogram data : each bin content is $d_i$ with the uncertainty $\sigma_{d_i}$
- histogram theory prediction : each bin content is $t_i$ with the uncertainty $\sigma_{t_i}$.

The $\chi^2$ is : $\displaystyle \chi^2=\sum_i\frac{(d_i-t_i)^2}{(\sigma_{d_i}+\sigma_{t_i})^2}$.

Is the uncertainty on $\chi^2$ defined ?

If so, what is it ?

Comment: What is "the uncertainty on $\chi^2$"? Do you mean the variance of $\chi^2$?

Comment: yes, exactly. Uncertainty is square root of variance.

Comment: What do you mean by "histogram theory prediction"? Do you mean the expected value of  $\ d_i\ $? If so, then the usual formula for the  $\ \chi^2\ $ statistic is  $\ \sum_\limits{i}\frac{\big(d_i−t_i\big)^2}{t_i}\ $, and it's not clear what  $\ \sigma_{t_i}\ $ means, since $\ t_i\ $ isn't a random variable.

Comment: On the other hand, when  $\ d_i\ $ and $\ t_i\ $ are two different sets of data for $\ n\ $ bins, the usual $\ 2\times n\ $ contingency table $\ \chi^2\ $
statistic is
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\Big(d_i−\frac{D(t_i+d_i)}{D+T}\Big)^2}{\frac{D(t_i+d_i)}{D+T}}+\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\Big(t_i−\frac{T(t_i+d_i)}{D+T}\Big)^2}{\frac{T(t_i+d_i)}{D+T}}
$$
where $\ D=\sum_\limits{i=1}^nd_i\ $ and $\ T=\sum_\limits{i=1}^nt_i\ $. So where did your formula for $\ \chi^2\ $ come from?

Comment: unfortunately, my level is too low for commenting...

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the uncertainty, that is quantified in terms of the standard deviation $\sigma_{X^{2}}$, which is the positive square root of the variance, on a quantity $X^{2}$ distributed according to the Chi-squared distribution with $k$ degrees of freedom, is well defined and is equal to
$$
\sigma_{X^{2}} = \sqrt{2k}
$$

See the answer to [Proof of Variance Formula for Central Chi-Squared Distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/172559/proof-of-variance-formula-for-central-chi-squared-distribution) for the derivation.

But the quantity $\chi^{2}$ exactly as you have defined
$$
\chi^{2} = \sum_{i} \frac{(d_{i} - t_{i})^{2}}{(\sigma_{d_{i}} + \sigma_{t_{i}})^{2}}
$$
does not look to be distributed according to the Chi-squared distribution.

**More detailed explanation.** Let $k$ be the number of bins and suppose we are given two histograms

\begin{align*}
d_{1}, &\dots, d_{k} \\
t_{1}, &\dots, t_{k}
\end{align*}

where the data summarized by these two histograms was drawn from random variables $D$ and $T$ respectively. For example, for the first histogram, the bin counts $d_{i}$ are outcomes of random variables $D_{i}$ where
$$
D_{i} = \text{#}\left\lbrace \text{data points in bin } i \right\rbrace
$$

The expected fraction of data points that fall in bin $i$ is equal to the probability $p_{i}$ that a point falls in that bin
$$
p_{i} = \int_{B_{i}} p_{D}(x)dx
$$
where $B_{i}$ denotes the interval of the bin $i$ and $p_{D}(x)$ is the probability density function (PDF) of the continuous random variable $D$. This is illustrated in the figure below

[image]

In the case when $D$ is discrete random variable, the probability $p_{i}$ is
$$
p_{i} = \sum_{x_{k} \in B_{i}} P_{D}(x_{k})
$$
where $P_{D}(x_{k})$ is the probability mass function (PMF) of $D$.

Then, the expected number of points in bin $i$ is
$$
\mathbb{E}[D_{i}] = n p_{i}
$$
where $n$ is the number of data points drawn from $D$.

We can compute the probability distribution of the counts $D_{i}$. If the data points are drawn independently from each other, then
$$
\mathbb{P}(D_{i} = j) = \binom{n}{j} p_{i}^{j} (1 - p_{i})^{n - j}
$$

Thus, $D_{i}$ is binomially distributed with the mean
$$
\mu_{D_{i}} = n p_{i}
$$
and variance
$$
\sigma_{D_{i}}^{2} = n p_{i} (1 - p_{i})
$$

Furthermore, for sufficiently large number of data points $n$, the binomial distribution of $D_{i}$ can be well approximated by a normally distributed random variable $X_{i}$ with mean $\mu_{D_{i}}$ and variance $\sigma_{D_{i}}^{2}$.

Correspondingly for the second histogram, where the bin counts $t_{i}$ are outcomes of random variables $T_{i}$, its distribution can be well approximated by a normally distributed random variable $Y_{i}$ with mean $\mu_{T_{i}}$ and variance $\sigma_{T_{i}}^{2}$.

Assuming that $D_{i}$ and $T_{i}$ are independent, then the difference
$$
X_{i} - Y_{i}
$$
can also be well approximated by a normally distributed random variable with mean $\mu_{D_{i}} - \mu_{T_{i}}$ and variance $\sigma_{D_{i}}^{2} + \sigma_{T_{i}}^{2}$. Then also, for large number of data points, the random variable
$$
Z_{i} = \frac{(X_{i} - Y_{i}) - (\mu_{D_{i}} - \mu_{T_{i}})
}{\sqrt{\sigma_{D_{i}}^{2} + \sigma_{T_{i}}^{2}}}
$$
has a standard Normal distribution, with zero mean and unit variance
$$
Z_{i} \sim N(0,1)
$$

The closest to the quantity that you have defined is
$$
X^{2} = \sum_{i=1}^{k}
\frac{
\left(
X_{i} - Y_{i}
\right)^{2}
}{\sigma_{D_{i}}^{2} + \sigma_{T_{i}}^{2}}
$$
when $\mu_{D_{i}} - \mu_{T_{i}} = 0$ (when the means are equal).

The sum of squares of independent identically distributed random variables $Z_{i}$ has Chi-squared distribution. However from this fact, as [lonza leggiera](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/632373/lonza-leggiera) pointed out in the comment, we cannot conclude that $X^{2}$ has Chi-squared distribution since $D_{i}$ for $i=1,...,k$ are not independent and consequently also the differences $X_{i} - Y_{i}$ are not independent.

**Update** When the bins are sufficiently small, the probability $p_{i}$ is sufficiently smaller than 1 and $p_{i}^{2}$ is negligible. Then we have

$$
\sigma_{D_{i}}^{2} = n p_{i} - p_{i}^{2} \approx n p_{i}
$$

And, despite the fact that random variables $D_{i}$ are not independent, we can use the covariance structure of random variables $D_{i}$ to prove the convergence in distribution to Chi-squared distribution with $k-1$ degrees of freedom for a random variable:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{k} \frac{(D_{i} - n p_{i})^{2}}{n p_{i}} \xrightarrow{d} \chi_{k-1}^{2}
$$

This is called Pearson’s theorem, the proof can be found in this [lecture notes](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-443-statistics-for-applications-fall-2006/lecture-notes/lecture11.pdf). However, the distribution of $D_{i} - T_{i}$ is not binomial and we cannot apply this theorem directly to $D_{i} - T_{i}$.

**Another update** As [lonza leggiera](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/632373/lonza-leggiera) pointed out in another comment, when $D_{i}$ and $T_{i}$ have the same mean $n p_{i}$, in addition to the assumption that they are independent, then the difference $D_{i} - T_{i}$ will have the same covariance structure as $D_{i}$. Thus, it seems like we can also prove the convergence for the difference $D_{i} - T_{i}$:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{k} \frac{ (D_{i} - T_{i})^{2} }{2 n p_{i}} \xrightarrow{d} \chi_{k-1}^{2}
$$

In case I misunderstood your question and you actually just want to perform a standard Chi-squared test, for example to assess goodness of fit of a histogram, you can take a look at the following [lecture notes](https://courses.cs.duke.edu/cps111/spring07/notes/10.pdf) on the goodness of fit test using the Chi-squared test.

Comment: Even if $\ \mu_{D_i}=\mu_{T_i}\ $ I don't believe the distribution your $\ X^2\ $ will have a standard $\ \chi^2\ $ distribution except under special circumstances. The problem is that $\ D_i\ $ and $\ D_j\ $ are (negatively) correlated $\big(\,\mathbb{Cov}\big(D_i,D_j\big)=$$-np_ip_j\ \big)$ for $\ i\ne j\ $, as are $\ T_i\ $ and $\ T_j\ $, so the distribution of $\ \sum_\limits{i=1}^k\frac{(D_i-T_i)^2}{\sigma_{D_i}^2+\sigma_{T_i}^2}\ $ can't be deduced from the fact that the sum of squares of *independent* standard normal variates has a $\ \chi^2\ $ distribution.

Comment: @lonzaleggiera Thank you, I already corrected my answer. Despite the fact that the random variables $D_{i}$ are not independent, we can still use this covariance structure and prove the convergence to $\chi_{k-1}^{2}$-distribution, but not for the difference. I added the Update with more explanation to my answer.

Comment: I think you can still do the same thing for the difference when $\ D_i\ $ and $\ T_i\ $ have the same mean  $\ np_i\ $ (and are independent). The vector $\ X=\Big(\frac{D_1−T_1}{\sqrt{2np_1}},
,\frac{D_2−T_2}{\sqrt{2np_2}},\dots,\frac{D_k−T_k}{\sqrt{2np_k}}\Big)\ $ then has the same covariance matrix, $\ I_{k\times k}−gg^T\ \big($ where $\ g^T=\big(\sqrt{p_1},\sqrt{p_2},\dots,\sqrt{p_k}\big) \big)$, as in the case of $\ D\ $ by itself.

Comment: Because $\ \big(D_1,D_2,\dots,D_k\big)\ $ and $\ \big(T_1,T_2,\dots,T_k\big)\ $ are multinomially distributed, $\ \ $ is approximately multivariate normally distributed for large $\ n\ $, and  $\ X^TX\ $ is therefore approximately $\ \chi^2\ $ distributed with  $\ k−1\ $ degrees of freedom.

Comment: @lonzaleggiera Very nice remark. Thank you for the comment. Yes this seems to be strong enough assumption, that $D_{i}$ and $T_{i}$ have the same mean (in addition that they are independent), to prove the convergence. I added it in another update to my answer.